# Split awk matches into separate command parameters

Tags: shell, awk

I want to push multiple files matching a pattern (from a CI result) as form encoded data using `curl`. Therefore I am trying to post process the `find` output to execute a command in the form of `curl -X POST -F "result=@$1" -F "result=@$2" localhost:80` (where the number of files is variable). I think something like this should be possible using AWK, but I don't quite get the expression to work. What I have so far is as follows:

```
find . -name build.log |
    awk '{print "-F '\''result=@"$1"'\''"}' ORS=' ' |
    awk -F '\n' '{curl -X POST $1 http://localhost:80}'
```

Could anyone help me fix the expression?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but maybe this is what you're trying to do:

```
curl -X POST $(find . -name 'build.log' -printf "-F 'result=@%p' ") http://localhost:80
```

To see what the find is outputting:

```
$ ls foo*
foo1  foo2

$ printf '<%s>\n' $(find . -name 'foo*' -printf "-F 'result=@%p' ")
<-F>
<'result=@./foo1'>
<-F>
<'result=@./foo2'>
```

Comment: Won’t that transform the output of the inner find command as a single argument for the curl command? Like “-F $1 -F $2 -F $3...”. I need it to be broken up in separate arguments: curl -F $1 -F $2 -F $3

Comment: No but why not try it and see? Do `printf '<%s>\n' $(find...)` for example.